# How to get list of database from SQL Server?

Tags: sql

As I know I can get the databases from SQL Server using `sys.databases`, however it's listing offline databases also. I keep checking for a flag which shows database online/offline status.

Can anyone help me with this ?

I want the databases from SQL Server which are online, just need to ignore the offline ones

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for the `state` column - [MSDN documentation is your friend always!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms178534.aspx)

```
state: tinyint

0 = ONLINE
1 = RESTORING
2 = RECOVERING
3 = RECOVERY_PENDING
4 = SUSPECT
5 = EMERGENCY
6 = OFFLINE
```

So if you want only online databases, use

```
SELECT (columns) FROM sys.databases WHERE state = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put where condition which will pick only online databases.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.databases db WHERE
db.state = 0
```

// [O for online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx) Check out all states here.

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, convert(varchar(20),databasepropertyex(name, 'Status')) status 
from master.dbo.sysdatabases 
order by name
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact if a database in SQL server is offline or not can be retrieved from the column `status` in `sys.sysdatabases`. The following SQL should in theory get you there:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.sysdatabases WHERE NOT status & 512 = 512;
```

(I did not test it but you should get the idea.)

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms179900(v=sql.90).aspx for details.

Comment: You'd now use sys.databases that has specific columns already. You wouldn't parse status or use sys.sysdatabases

Answer (score 0):

On MSSql - Server try the following statement

```
select state , state_desc from sys.databases
```

This will show you the current state of the Database

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.databases db WHERE
db.state = 0 and owner_sid <> 0x01
```

You can skip system databases, list only user databases

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer ?

Comment: I fail to see how this adds anything to previous answers? Also, please indent your code with four spaces to put it in a code block.